# Buscar palavra com file_get_contents

Tags: php, file-get-contents

Como posso usar o file_get_contents para buscar a palavra "equipe" no site e se ele localizar a palavra dar um echo na palavra?

```
<?php

$content = file_get_contents( 'https://www.hostgator.com.br' );

$busca = 'equipe ';

?>
```

Comment: Você diz buscar equipe dentro do html retornado? ou fazer uma busca por equipe na caixa de pesquisa do site e pegar o resultado ?

Comment: buscar equipe dentro do html

Comment: se ele encontrar a palavra equipe no html dar um echo com a palavra equipe

Answer (score 5):

Pode usar `preg_match_all()` para fazer essa pesquisa, o resultados são armazenados no terceiro argumento(`$matches`).

```
<?php
   $content = file_get_contents( 'https://www.hostgator.com.br' );
   $regex = '/equipe/';
   preg_match_all($regex, $content, $matches);

   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($matches);
```

Comment: O meu `strpos` é mais rápido! ná ná ná ná ná ná!

Comment: @WallaceMaxters eu fui 11 segundo mais rápido que o `strpos()` haha :P

Comment: Dei uma pequena alfinetada na sua regex na minha resposta, kkkkkkk

Answer (score 5):

Utilize a função `strpos` para encontrar a primeira ocorrência da string.

```
$content = file_get_contents( 'https://www.hostgator.com.br' );


if (strpos($content, 'equipe') !== FALSE) {
    echo "tem a palavra";
}
```

Caso preciso encontrar a palavra independente de maiúscula ou minúscula, você pode usar `stripos`.

Geralmente as expressões regulares costumam ser mais lentas. Caso a string seja apenas uma palavra específica, você poderá escolher `strpos`, que é mais simples.

Comment: Não retornou nada.

Comment: Tem um erro no código. Uma variável é `$contents` e outra é `$content`. Vou arrumar

Comment: Nem percebi....

Answer (score 2):

Pode ser feito das seguintes formas, sendo também que tem muitas outros formas:

Nessa primeira percorrendo linha por linha e dando **echo** nas palavras encontradas:

```
<?php

$fileContent = file_get_contents('https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipe');

foreach (preg_split('/\n/', $fileContent) as $value) {

  $pattern = '/equipe/';//Padrão a ser encontrado na string $fileContent
  if (preg_match_all($pattern, $value, $matches)) {

    foreach ($matches[0] as $matche) {

      echo $matche . '<br>';

    }

  }

}
```

Ou também dessa forma pesquisando em toda a string:

```
<?php

$fileContent = file_get_contents('https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipe');

$pattern = '/equipe/';//Padrão a ser encontrado na string $value
if (preg_match_all($pattern, $fileContent, $matches)) {

  foreach ($matches[0] as $matche) {
    echo $matche . '<br>';
  }

}
```